# Translation of 出証意 and 長官殿

Tags: words, translation, meaning

These are from a patent related document and I can't understand very well.

They are used like these：

1) 特許庁長官殿
2) 出証意2012

Can anyone help me?

Comment: this site discourages pure translation questions. you will have an easier time getting answers to questions like this on  lang-8.com or http://esaura.cc/

Comment: Are you sure the second one is not an abbreviated code of something? It looks so.

Comment: Can you give some context of the second term?

Comment: Yes, the second one can be a code. I'm not sure. It is written in footer just like this: 出証意2012. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

長官 is the top person of that institute. 殿 is a polite affix attached after people's name or title in business or formal occasions, contrasted with 様 used in personal occasions. For the second part, it is not an ordinary Japanese, and my guess is that it is an abbreviated code used for sorting the documents, shortened from something like "出願証 意匠 2012年" "proof of application, classification: design, submitted year: 2012".

証 may stand for something more or different.

Comment: I do not know if there is a word 出願証, but if there is, it probably means “certificate of application,” not “application form.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto It's more like "proof", but I took it that way. Do you have an alternative idea?

Comment: I think that “proof of application” (a document which proves that you applied for something) is different from “application form” (a document you fill and submit to apply for something).

Comment: I have never said that 証 may stand for something different from “proof.”  What I said is that 証 does not probably mean “form,” because you claimed so in an earlier revision of the answer.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Sorry.I edited it.

Answer (score 3):

特許庁長官殿 means “Commissioner, Patent Office” with a polite suffix, as you and sawa explained.

出証意 is not a word.  From what I learned from the web, I think that it appears in a reference number of a certificate of application documents and acceptance of application (出願書類及び出願受付情報に関する証明書) for a design (意匠) in the form 出証意2012-1234567.

Answer (score 1):

The first one may be translated as Commissioner Patent Office.